# glyphicon glyphicon-globe not rendering properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I already have a bootstrap library and a font library too. My problem is the class `glyphicon glyphicon-globe` won't render properly in my browser. Can someone help me resolve the issue?

Any help is much appreciated.TIA

Comment: Font awesome and glyphicon are different. please check you added glyphicon js and css correctly

Comment: so what is the css for glyphicon? bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css ?

Comment: show your code also. How did you use it?

Comment: i just added this line of code
  <!-- CORE CSS -->
  <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: add your HTML code as well

Comment: also check your console that your are not getting any error regarding css or js

Comment: and your browser is ???

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the path to the folder is correctly specified.

Comment: yes here
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />